# How to configure Hive to use Spark?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-spark

I have a problem using Hive on Spark. I have installed a single-node HDP 2.1 (Hadoop 2.4) via Ambari on my CentOS 6.5. I'm trying to run Hive on Spark, so I used this instructions:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

I already downloaded the "Prebuilt for Hadoop 2.4"-version of Spark, which i found on the official Apache Spark website. So I started the Master with:

```
./spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

Then the worker with:

```
./spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://hadoop.hortonworks:7077
```

And then I started Hive with this prompt:

```
hive –-auxpath /SharedFiles/spark-1.0.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

Then, according to the instructions, i had to change the execution engine of hive to spark with this prompt:

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;,
```

And the result is:

```
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: 'SET hive.execution.engine=spark' FAILED in validation : Invalid value.. expects one of [mr, tez].
```

So if I try to launch a simple Hive Query, I can see on my hadoop.hortonwork:8088 that the launched job is a MapReduce-Job.

**Now to my question**: How can I change the execution engine of Hive so that Hive uses Spark instead of MapReduce? Are there any other ways to change it? (I already tried to change it via ambari and at the hive-site.xml)

Comment: Could could please confirm that you followed the instructions under "Configuring Hive" -- especially Item 1? (Basically, you need to go download the "Hive on Spark" development branch and build it yourself.) This is bleeding edge stuff, and a plain off-the-shelf Hive doesn't support it yet.

Comment: Hive-on-Spark is still a work in progress... if you're trying to do anything serious with it I'd strongly discourage you at this point.

Comment: **Thanks for your answers**. Maybe this is the cause of some other error-messages concerning Hive on Spark. I accidentally skipped step 1. I think I'll setup a new Hadoop on my server without using Hortonworks or Cloudera.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change in hive configuration properties like this....

in `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>spark</value>
  <description>
    Chooses execution engine.
  </description>
</property>
```

Comment: Should be:<property> 
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>spark</value>
  <description>
    Chooses execution engine.
  </description>
</property>

Answer (score 5):

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
```

try this command it will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

set hive.execution.engine=spark; This is introduced in Hive 1.1+ onward. I think your hive version is older than Hive 1.1.

[image]
Resource: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

Answer (score 0):

in hive>conf>hive-site.xml
set the value of hive.execution.engine to spark.

```
  </property> 
    <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
    <value>spark</value>
  </property>
```